# How to stream web media content to my smart TV via DLNA?

Tags: 12.04, streaming, dlna

I want to stream a cloud based media to my tv .. I've installed DLNA server on my ubuntu pc but i want to share web content without downloading it to my pc.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a Yamaha RX-V473 that recently stopped playing internet radio stations, because it was integrated with the now defunct Vtuner service. The update to fix this is only available for newer products.

The RX-V473 has the possibility to access DLNA servers and I had it hooked up to an Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with Rygel installed (`sudo apt install rygel`) and media sharing in Ubuntu settings set to Active.

[image: Rygel options in Ubuntu settings]

Playing your own MP3 files collection is working and easy and even mp3 files in [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com), those in Google Drive or any other files on any server that can be accessed with the Files browser can be accessed by adding the  folder in *Ubuntu Settings > Sharing.* This can be Appletalk files over the `afp://` protocol, FTP, FTPS, NFS, SMB, SFTP, SSH, DAV or DAVS shares. You name it, it works. But I want to listen to internet radio station SomaFM on my stereo and this option is not (yet) present in the *Sharing* section of Ubuntu settings.

To stream SomaFM over DLNA (Rygel) to your DLNA client you need to edit `rygel.conf`, specifically the one in `$HOME/.config/rygel.conf`.

Go to the section `[GstLaunch]` and edit the changes as seen below.

I have added the complete section of a working version here.

```
[GstLaunch]
enabled=true
launch-items=audiotestsrc;soma;drone

audiotestsrc-title=Audiotestsrc
audiotestsrc-mime=audio/x-wav
audiotestsrc-launch=audiotestsrc ! wavenc

soma-title=SomaFM SpaceStation
soma-mime=audio/mpeg
soma-launch=souphttpsrc iradio-mode=false location=http://ice2.somafm.com/spacestation-128-mp3 

drone-title=SomaFM Dronezone
drone-mime=audio/mpeg
drone-launch=souphttpsrc iradio-mode=false location=http://ice2.somafm.com/dronezone-128-mp3
```

**(Beware there should not be a return between `false` and `location`! Just a space) It should be one line**

Now when the receiver is going to search for DLNA servers under the server button it sees the media share from Rygel and GstLaunch. Select GstLaunch and 3 stations appear, *Audiotestsrc* will produce a test tone for testing, while *SomaFM SpaceStation* and *SomaFM Dronezone* will play the relevant streams.

You can add as many Internet radio stations as you want.

- To check if the stream url is working open VLC and go to *Media > Network stream* and enter the URL. If VLC starts producing music the stream URL is correct.
- Every time you edit/change `rygel.conf` you need to click *Media sharing* off and on in Ubuntu Settings to restart Rygel.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the capabilities of your SmartTV or how your SmartTV is connected to the DNLA server. As far as I know my Samsung SmartTV can only access media that is stored on the DNLA server thus it might not be possible (without additional third party software). For a start make sure that your router allows traffic via DNLA port (TCP/UDP 5001) to your TV because that was an issue I had to deal with when I installed DNLA on a computer on my network. It might be worth checking with the cloud provider if there is a possibility to access their service with a SmartTV using dedicated App.

Cheers,

Comment: Supposing that my TV supports that, is it possible to configure my dlna server to point to a media link and share it via dlna ?

Answer (score 0):

In software (Linux Mint/Ubuntu..)- find and install Rygel. It is a DNLA server. Then move the movies you want to watch into your movies folder. You can then access this through your Smart TV (or Roku or AppleTV box).

Comment: Could you please be more specific like adding the commands to install Rygel and how to configure it (before the system deletes your answer automatically as "low quality")  ;-)